# Http request to emulate forms with multi-value fields

Tags: forms, http, file-upload, multipartform-data

I have being working with forms like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="script.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset id="form-1">
        <legend>Form-1</legend>
        Some Field:
        <input type="text" name="formsets[0][somefield]" />
        Another Field:
        <input type="text" name="formsets[0][anotherfield]" />
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset id="form-2">
        <legend>Form-2</legend>
        Some Text:
        <textarea name="formsets[1][sometext]"></textarea>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Upload Pictures:</legend>
            <input type="file" name="formsets[1][pictures][0]" />
            <input type="file" name="formsets[1][pictures][1]" />
        </fieldset>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="buttons">
        <input type="submit" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

In PHP I then use loops to process incoming data in $_POST and $_FILES arrays. For educational purposes I want to know what the resulting http request looks like when the form is submitted to the server?

So, I have been playing around with multpart/form-data and already know about the boundary stuff, this far I've had no problems, but when it comes to sending form requests that have multi-value fields I can't do much. I've been told to use the "multipart/mixed"  and nesting chunks with their own boundaries but it didn't work for me.

So, do you help me build the http request code to achieve that?